# How to get a style from inspect and use it in CSS

Tags: html, css, angular, styles, ngx-editor

In my angular project I imported the ngx-editor and I'm trying to make the editor height to become smaller. I did inspect element and I'm able to modify the height in the inspect element but when I copy the .nw-editor{ .. } from the inspect element and paste it in my css file, it didn't change the height for some reason.

Any suggestion or advice on how can I make the height to become smaller?.

I copy this in my scss and also in my global style.scss file but it's not working.

```
.nw-editor {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;    // I try to change the height here
    background: #fff;
    cursor: text;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

my HTML

```
// I also try to change the height from here but still not working

  <ngx-wig [(ngModel)]="post.description.features" style="height: 121px"></ngx-wig>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you did it right, you can get the build with the command below

```
ng build --output-hashing=all
```